# magento site search reporting/analytics

Tags: search, google-analytics, magento-1.7

I'm working with a client to improve their site search results through the Magento search functionality. We have set up redirects for the top searched terms. My question is, how am I able to track conversions/revenue for these terms now that I no longer have search query parameters on the url?

The client wants to be able to see the effect these search changes have on conversion rate/revenue but I can't seem to figure out how to set this up in GA and Magento doesn't seem to have report that provides this data. Any help is appreciated.

Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2):

You can try two different approach :

1. Either by getting the search term by url rewrite table using your current url.
2. Or you can use the session variables by setting the search teams in the session and getting at required place.

Hope this will help you!